# How to get consecutive word combinations of n words from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Say I have an integer value `n` and following list

```
myList = ["This", "is", "a",  "great", "list"]
n = 2
```

How can I split this list in an output list that "splits" `myList` into another list where each element is `n` consecutive words. Like this

```
outputList = ["This is", "is a", "a great",  "great list"]
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far, looking at it can be done with a simple loop?

Comment: I only got it to work for n = 1 so far but the for loop I used for that doesn't account for n. Honestly I'm a bot lost as to how to tackle that task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use nested loops.

So, the thing you'd need to do here is to use nested loops. The outer loop grabs the first word, and the inner loops grab each subsequent word.

So, something like this:

```
myList = ["This", "is", "a",  "great", "list"]
n = 2

final = []
for i in range(len(myList) - n + 1):
  if n>1:
    temp = myList[i]
    for j in range(n-1):
      temp += " " + myList[i+j+1]
    final.append(temp)
  else:
    final.append(myList[i])
```

After executing the loop, we get a value for final equal to this:

```
['This is', 'is a', 'a great', 'great list']
```

For n=3, we get the following list:

```
['This is a', 'is a great', 'a great list']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` combined with generator expressions:

```
>>> [" ".join(t) for t in zip(*(myList[i:] for i in range(n)))]
['This is', 'is a', 'a great', 'great list']
```

for `n = 3`:

```
['This is a', 'is a great', 'a great list']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work :-

```py
myList = ["This", "is", "a",  "great", "list"]
n = 2
tempN = n

res = []

for i in range(len(myList)-n+1):
    start, tempRes = myList[i], ""

    for j in range(i, len(myList)):
        if tempN>0:
            if tempN == 1:
                tempRes += f"{myList[j]}"
            else:
                tempRes += f"{myList[j]} "

            tempN -= 1
    else:
        res.append(tempRes)
        tempN = n

print(res)
```

What happens here is that, the first loop iterates through `myList` till the penultimate element, since the last element remains single after concatenation; and takes an element. With respect to the index of that element the inner loop iterates `n` times so as to concatenate its `n` adjacent partners. The outer `if` checks the exiting condition, which is when `n` is equal to 0. The inner `if-else` is just to format the string so that there is no space at the end of the string.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for noting me, Bug has been fixed...

Answer (score 0):

A different form of the list comprehension / generator expression solution:

```
[" ".join(myList[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(myList)-n+1)]
```

produces for, e.g., `n=3`:

```
['This is a', 'is a great', 'a great list']
```